# Get attributes with Latitude and Longitude in shapefile as a CSV file

Tags: shapefile, data

I have some shapefiles of geodata. I need to add that into a database and access attributes with Latitude and Longitude in shapefile. So how can I solve using any type of programming language and database?

Comment: Maybe you should concretize your question a bit...I'm sure that if you provide details on which software/programming language you want to use, someone knows help.

Answer (score 1):

The [Geospatial Data Abstraction Library (GDAL)](http://www.gdal.org/) has command-line tools that will do this.  Look into [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) - the list of formats that can be used in ogr commands is [here](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html).

I know this will work for shapefile to csv for points - if you're dealing with polygons or lines it might be a bit more complex, and it might be helpful to search for 'polygon shapefile to csv' or similar.

I'll mention GDAL is also employed in QGIS, among other open source tools, and these functions can often be employed through their GUIs or associated programming tools (e.g., using python w/ QGIS).